# How do I model the correct regression in excel(for R)

Tags: r, regression, finance

I am doing an anlysis for Greenium in Bonds. I am matching comparable bonds with same maturities,etc.

Now i have a datasets with matched bonds(total of 20) with their yields.

Since my dependant variable are the yields and independant a categorical variable(green or not) I am unsure how excactly i can do a regression for all bonds since they are paired due to the matching…

Calculating spread of matched bonds and pasting them in one column would yield one column for the dependant variable but i could no longer use my independant (green or not) since both bonds would be included in the result…

Comment: What is the objective of your analysis??

Comment: Objective is to find out if there is a Greenium present, as in yields for green bonds are lower than comparable conventional bonds. Thats why they are matched 1:1 bud i have a bunch of those 1:1 pairs and want to analyse them all together (the pairs) Am a statistics noob and my capabilities end with a simple regression and t test :S

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow.  If I read your post correctly, it seems you have told us you already have a categorical variable that indicates the presence of "greenium."  What, then, would it mean to "find out" whether it is present?

Comment: I have a categorical variable that shows if the bond is green or not. Now I have the yields for one pair. One pair consists of 1x green bond with matched characteristics to 1x converntional bond. Now I need to find out if there is a difference in yields and if there is between those two and the green bond has lower yields then there would be a greenium present. I have around 100 of those pairs. I am unsure how to run a regression for all those bonds together that is my problem, basically how am I going to build a regression for all matched pairs?

Comment: The nature of the data is becoming clearer, but your question remains opaque. One question you seem to ask is "if there is a difference in yields." Do you mean a difference in *each pair* or an *average* difference?

Comment: That's basically how far I have came and am unsure what the best course of analysis would be for this data set.  I guess I would prefer a difference if there is a significance across all pairs together not just each pair individually since then I would have to display a table of all pairs (100+) individually and that could be quite large I think so an average differnce.

Comment: Do a paired t-test.

Comment: Alright thank you, opinions on doing regressions too? Is it even possible/meaningful with this data set?

Comment: Regression techniques include several models that are equivalent to paired t-tests.